# How to add a ppa from a launchpad link

Tags: ppa, launchpad

How can I add this ppa:

https://launchpad.net/~ermshiperete/+archive/ubuntu/monodevelop

to Ubuntu by a command?

So given a launchpad link how can I created the appropriate command?

Comment: @kos: That post does not talk about how to find the code from the link.

Comment: Your question doesn't ask how to find the code from the link, it asks "how to add this ppa to Ubuntu by a command", and that is what the answer you accepted is about, the name of the PPA is there only incidentally. Not meaning to be harsh, but really you didn't see the (pretty big) "Adding this PPA to your system" paragraph on the link?

Comment: Also *it does* talk about how to find the code from the link. Quoting the accepted answer: "You have to enter the PPA in the box. It can be found in BOLD on the launchpad page.", and here's the picture below that: http://i.stack.imgur.com/A7osv.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Other Software tab in Software & Updates

```
sudo software-properties-gtk --open-tab=1
```

click on Add

[image]

type in the ppa - then click on Add Source

[image]

Then click on Close.

Now install your package.

```
sudo apt-get install monodevelop
```

Comment: The `--open-tab=1` thing is great.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ermshiperete/monodevelop
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ****
```

Where **** is the name of the package that you wish to install.